# Is it possible to snip a certain number of pixels from a specified side of an image, without specifying the image's final width and height?

Tags: image-processing

It seems that `ImageCrop` allows one to specify the *final* size of the image.  For example, `ImageCrop[image, size, spec]` crops image `image` to size `size`, and one can specify which side of the image the pixels should be taken from, using `spec`.

But, what if I don't know the final size `size` of the image? What if I just want to snip 10 pixels from the right side of the image? I might want to do this for a series of images, whose sizes are not known (at least immediately).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same basic solution using image take but wrapped up a little:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Crop[img_, {{dxl_, dxr_}, {dyl_, dyu_}}] := ImageTake[img, {dyl, -dyu}, {dxl, -dxr}]
```

Where `dxl`, `dxr`, `dyl`, `dyu` represent the x lext, x right, y lower and y upper sizes of crop.

```
Crop[img,{{10, 10}, {25, 25}}]
```

Removes 10 pixels from the left and right edges and 25 from the bottom and top.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then apply the same trim a group of images held in a list, by the following

```
images={im1,im2,im3,im4,...,imn};

Crop[#,{{0,10},{5,0}}]&/@images
```

Comment: When `ImageTake` is provided with negative arguments, it counts down from `ImageDimensions`, like `Part`

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for that, I didn't really pick that up from the docs. Which reduces this pretty much to the same as your solution :)

Comment: From the help `-n ... last n elements` :)

Comment: @Belisarius It must be the way I read them :)  I took, `ImageTake[image,-n]` gives an image consisting of the last n rows of image to mean you got rows N-n+1 to N,  not,  0 to N-n. As in -3 gives you the last 3 rows, not everything but the last 3 rows.

Comment: Well, you know: [Mma docs have been written by 10^7 monkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)

Comment: @belisarius It's the technique I apply to write most of my code ;)

Answer (score 12):

Your code would be

```
ImageTake[i, All, {1, -11}]
```

Examples:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];
ImageTake[img, {25, -25}, {10, -10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ImageTake[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], {180, -180}, {180, -180}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! OK, I need to specify `size` as `All`. Cool!

Comment: @MatthiasOdisio [**OBOE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `ImageTake`, `ImagePad` will do the job using the syntax `ImagePad[img, {{left, right}, {bottom, top}}]`:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];
In[10]:= ImagePad[img, {{0, -10}, {0, 0}}] == ImageTake[img, All, {1, -11}]
Out[10]= True
```

Note the difference between taking up to the last minus 10th column and removing 10 columns.