# Cropping a Plot without rasterization

Tags: plotting, graphics

Suppose that I make a plot of $x^2$ vs. $x$:

```
myPlot = Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: myPlot1]

If I click on the plot, I see the orange handles with which I can resize the plot:

[image: myPlot2]

Now, suppose that I want to actually crop the plot -- I would like to effectively shrink the orange box so that some of the plot is actually cropped.  (*Why in the world would I want to do this?*  It's a long story...)

I have found, from [answers to a question that I previously asked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8686/is-it-possible-to-snip-a-certain-number-of-pixels-from-a-specified-side-of-an-im), that this is possible using `ImagePad` with negative arguments.  For example, suppose that I want to crop 40 pixels off the right side of the plot.  I can do the following:

```
ImagePad[myPlot, {{0, -45}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image: myPlot3]

It looks good so far.  ***However,*** when I resize the resulting cropped plot by dragging the orange handles, it looks like the image has been rasterized:

[image: myPlot4]

**But, in contrast, I need the image to remain a vector image (non-rasterized) after cropping.**  Is that possible?  I am running both version 8 and 9.

Comment: Just using `PlotRange` is no option? Like: `Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0.5}, Automatic}]`

Comment: Or after the fact: Show[plot, PlotRange -> ...]

Comment: @PinguinDirk Unfortunately, no, just `PlotRange` is not an option for me.  I need to be able to crop the *entire* image -- **including** white space, frames, frame ticks, and frame labels.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure I understand.  Why can't you just not use frames and labels then?  Show[... Frame -> False]

Comment: @Szabolcs Unfortunately, it's a long story.  I have made some multipanel figures using the `LevelScheme` package, but the resulting composite graphics boxes have whitespace that I need to remove on one side.  So the "plot" that I need to crop without rasterization is actually a `Graphics` box containing the output of some `LevelScheme` commands (I just thought I'd use `Plot` as a minimal working example in this question).  And although the `LevelScheme` contains a `Margins` option, I cannot use it without affecting the sizes of the multipanel plots.

Comment: @Andrew LevelScheme doesn't use Mathematica's special built-in frame.  It draws its own frame, so setting PlotRange on the output should in fact crop the frame as well.

Comment: @Szabolcs Hmm, interesting... I will try this now.  Thanks.

Comment: @Szabolcs Unfortunately, setting `PlotRange` on the output of LevelScheme ***also*** (in addition to effectively cropping) changes the aspect ratios of the individual plots within the LevelScheme frame.  Unfortunately, I need to change the size of (or crop) the LevelScheme frame without altering the sizes or aspect ratios of the plots within the frame.

Comment: @Andrew Have you tried changing the AspectRatio setting to compensate?

Comment: @Szabolcs No, but that is a *very* good point.

Comment: Strongly related: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33824/280), [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5568/280).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html) (this is what the interactive editor does basically).

Example:  The variable `crop` consists of image scaled coordinates in the order

```
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}
```

In this example, the value `ymax` is greater than one, which extends the image beyond the boundary of the original plot.

```
myPlot = Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True];
croppedPlot =
 With[{iSize = 350. {1, 1/GoldenRatio},
       crop = {{0.1, 0.8}, {0.2, 1.2}}}, 
   Graphics[
    Inset[Show[myPlot, ImageSize -> iSize], {0., 0.}, ImageScaled[{0., 0.}]],
    PlotRange -> crop iSize, ImageSize -> crop iSize]
   ];
Framed[croppedPlot, FrameMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 10):

I just realized from [this Wolfram page](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsLayout.html) that one can crop the "orange box" by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**dragging** one of the orange handles.

```
myPlot = Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: original]

and obtain

[image: new]

This seems to work pretty well for the question that I asked.  A programmatic method would be better, but this use of the front end is OK.

Comment: (+1)Very Nice Solution. :)

Comment: How can I export the cropped picture?